# Wordpress gallery shortag

Tags: php, gallery

I'm creating a simple slideshow on the side where i want to show 4 images from a post, i searched around i found this code that simply uses the build in gallery function

```
<li><?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery id="'.$post->ID.'"]'); ?></li>
```

the problem is that it spits out the entire gallery...
is there noway to limit this to 2,3 ?

i tried to use

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

but for some reason, i didnt work... I guess it because all my posts are made of is a gallery of images

all help is appreciated
regards

Comment: you can check Gallery function in gallery plugin an can modified it as per your requirement or may create a new one which fulfill you needs !!

Comment: but this functions is in its core, where do i find it to make changes to it

Comment: copy code from core gallery shortcode, then remove_shortcode('gallery'), then add yours (using add_shortcode('gallery','my_gallery_shortocode'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to limit the gallery query in the shortcode_gallery function. However, you can get the child attachments of a post using the following.

```
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'numberposts' => 5) );
```

You will need to iterate through the attachments and build out your gallery HTML.

Comment: this was really simple imo and i got it work right away thanks alot ;)

Answer (score 0):

To exclude an image from the WordPress Gallery you would use something like this:

```
[gallery link="file"  columns="4" exclude="2092,2091,2068"]
```

*Here's a breakdown of the code above:*

**gallery link="file"**

This links the image to the image file instead of the attachment post. Useful if you plan on using a thickbox or lightbox effect).

**columns="4"** 
   This controls the images per row.

**exclude="2092,2091,2068"**    This excludes the images that have the id matching the numbers used. There might be other ways to get the number ID for the images, but the way I get them is to go to your Media Browser by clicking on the Medial Link in the left side tool-bar. Next click on an image you want to exclude. You will see it's number ID in the URL of your  browser.

Comment: yes but when u have a gallery of 20 images you would rather have it just limit the output then exclude 18 out them

Comment: If that's the case, then why even use the gallery. You could simply use the image ID's or the actual image URL to display them. If your trying to display a random 4 images of a given post, maybe using the gallery short-code isn't the best route. It was your idea to use the gallery, I just showed you how you could do it ;}

Comment: as i am fairly new to wordpress I'm trying whatever is given to me, if you read my question you'll see that I've tried get_the_post_thumbnail but it didn't work I found the gallery shorttag and it actually showed the images I posted opposite to everything else i tried, and i took for granted it should be an easy task to limit the output. I now know it isn't.